# Facebook - Posting .swf to user's wall with PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, flash, facebook-php-sdk

I used to do this using the `stream.publish` method, where I specified the source file for my .swf along with other parameters to present the media, but this is now deprecated. How can I do this using the Graph API? Specifically the Facebook PHP SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the php sdk, you can post them like this:

```
$facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array(
    'type'=>'video',
    'source'=>'http://www.hackerdude.com/channels-test/swfscout_VideoSample.swf',
    'picture'=> 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    'name'=> 'Facebook Dialogs',
    'caption'=> 'Reference',
    'description'=> 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.',
);
```

You should be able to add the `link` attribute to the mix, but there seem to be a [bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/502967809730190) in facebook's api at this moment that make the posts with `link` in it prevent embedding the `swf`. this way it will be embedded but the name in the resulting post will point to the `swf` file which is not good. Same values with link posted with the [FB.ui](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) from the `js sdk` doesn't exhibit this behavior.

One workaround could be to create links with the proper opengraph meta tags, and post that as `type => 'link'`.

**the html file** (video brought to you by youtube)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fly, you fools!</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Fly, you fools!" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Content for Description" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/meOCdyS7ORE/mqdefault.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Content for caption"/>
    <meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/meOCdyS7ORE?version=3&autohide=1">
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="640">
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="360">
</head>
<body>
<script>
    window.location = 'http://disney.com'; // redirecting users who's clicking on the link, wont affect crawlers since its in js.
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**php sdk call to share it**

```
$this->facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array(
    'type' => 'link',
    'link' => 'http://.../', // put the html file's location here
));
```

Comment: Thank you complex, this is what's supposed to be done, but it seems to not work. It seems that at the moment FB is bugging out on this specific kind of post (lucky me), so I guess I'll have to wait until it resolves.